# Windows 8 and Ubuntu Dual-boot: Many duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates, questions

It seems to me that Ask Ubuntu is flooded with questions about Windows 8 and Ubuntu dual-booting systems. Should we be concerned about SE quality and over-asked questions? Here are two examples, ([After installing Ubuntu I can't boot Windows 8 anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229858/after-installing-ubuntu-i-cant-boot-windows-8-anymore?rq=1)) and (https://askubuntu.com/questions/239637/bought-a-windows8-system-from-store-installed-ubuntu-windows-installer-but-it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Dupe it!

Mark as duplicate (if you have sufficient privileges) or flag it as such. A header with the appropriate message will direct users to the right duplicate with the most useful posts.

In my opinion this is not different from any other issue we had about a flood of similar/near identical questions when Ubuntu mobile/touch was presented.

Comment: Same question as for @AvatarParto's post: What is the best answer to these questions? [This one?](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/40581) Should it be broken down into better consumable chunks? Where to redirect the user that is on average to lazy to read through a mammoth answer, but will proceed after his first problem was solved?

Answer (score 2):

Yes true - and those questions are duplicate often too, when solution is the same: to enable/disable Uefi/Efi - Bios for to get around black or blue screen.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to create like a mega answer on dual-booting ubuntu with windows 8 because the questions are just increasing at an alarming rate? Just try a search for questions tagged `[windows-8]`, there are like thousands of them...

If we create a mega answer touching on dual booting, UEFI, etc. Anyone posting *any* question tagged `windows-8` will have to read the mega answer first.

Comment: I think that we already [have that](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/40581) and users see this huge amout of text that doesn't seem to relate to their particular question or solves their problem quickly. So that instead may be the **cause** why we get so many duplicates to this question. I think it should be broken down into several good questions with good answers more [like so (shameless I know)](http://superuser.com/a/680098/252532).