# New tag proposal: meta tags "Concern" and "Quality"

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think that a [concern](/questions/tagged/concern) tag and [quality](/questions/tagged/quality) tag should be added. This question ([Windows 8 and Ubuntu Dual-boot: Many duplicates](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6895/windows-8-and-ubuntu-dual-boot-many-duplicates)) could use these tags as well as many other meta questions.

Tag uses and definitions:

Concern: This tag is for questions that are asking about a concern for Ask Ubuntu. Users concerned about specific issues may use this tag.

Quality: This tag indicates a question about question, answer, comment, or Stack Exchange quality. Users asking questions about improving their questions may use this tag.

Comment: How can I improve this question to receive up-votes? What do you suggest @mateo?

Comment: oh, meta is slightly diffrent than the main site, as votes on this question are in support/against the feature-request, not denoting quality of the question(also on meta rep dosn't matter)

Comment: expanding the use cases may help, or if you feal more strongly about one tag you might seperate the tag requests, so we might explore both in greater detail.

Comment: @mateo At this point, I am afraid that doing so would cost me more reputation points. I have flagged this question for deletion.

Comment: meta questions/answers have no effect on rep... voting is pure agree/disagree.

Comment: @mateo, really? I never noticed that. Thank you for informing me. That is an interesting concept. That helps.

Comment: meta tags on meta ... That's a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We usually don't end up using tags like concern because these are usually ubiquitous, and can be applied almost anywhere. Much like the [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/problem) tag on the main site everyone has a concern/problem, the more important thing is what the concern is about.

Also on meta there is a small sub-set of required tags, of which one must be included.

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Some alternatives to "quality" may be better to put a tag that is in line with why there is aquestion of quality, downvotes, close reasons, editing, translation, ect.