# Can I get a peer review on my answer to a Windows 8 / SSD / dual-boot question?

Tags: discussion

I got confused with the [various questions about Windows 8](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6895/windows-8-and-ubuntu-dual-boot-many-duplicates), SSDs and dual-booting, and none seemed to cover all three, so I made my own specific one. [1] I [answered it](https://askubuntu.com/a/317709/7146) too :) My answer is not drawn from experience, but from trawling through the various options presented in other answers.

Can I get a peer review on my answer? (If this is not the appropriate forum to make this request, which is?)

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/316670/how-do-i-dual-boot-12-04-2-windows-8-on-an-ssd-hdd-machine

**Update:** I think my answer may be incorrect because it assumes an SSD that can hold both OSes. Having reviewed the relative sizes, I am no longer sure this is the case. I'm leaving the answer for peer review while I continue researching. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: found some related questions about pure Ubuntu (not dual-boot) and linked to them on the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answers on this website are **peer reviewed**. That is the very basic principle of the Stack Exchange QA websites based on reputation. Your answer will be voted down if it is incorrect. Comments will be left if needed.

It is unclear to me what else we could say here.

If you really want feedback: well if you present a procedure (step by step) it is more logical to use numbering than bullets. But hey... that does not touch the content of your question/answer.